# Jenkins Subversion plugin 2.4 option --non-interactive

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone knows how to find out if the [Subversion plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) 2.4 for Jenkins uses --non-interactive or --no-auth-cache when check out?
The command should be: `svn co http://svn.....  /home/user/test1/`
I suspect it uses --no-auth-cache because it does not create the svn.simple folder in the check out directory.

I want to change this option to --non-interactive (if it's possible).